# default image from localhost rather than loading from cloudinary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloudinary

I am using cloudinary to store user avatars in my rails 4 application. I also have a placeholder image in my image assets. I wanted to know that if a user hasnt uploaded his avatar, how do i load it from the localhost.

As of now i have to add checks as

```
- if user.avatar.present?
  = cl_image_tag(user.avatar.filename, width: 46, height: 46)
- else
  = image_tag 'default.png', style: 'width:46px; height:46px;'
```

i can specify a default image as

```
= cl_image_tag(user.avatar.filename, width: 46, height: 46, default: 'default.png')
```

but the default image has to be stored on cloudinary. I dont want to store it on cloudinary since cloudinary charges for data transfer. hence, i have stored 'default.png' is stored in assets. 'cl_image_tag' is a helper provided by cloudinary to load images from there.

Comment: store the default image `assets/images` folder.

Comment: @Sampat its stored there. the issue is i want to only write 'user.avatar.filename' and it display the image from assets if no image is uploaded else should retrieve from cloudinary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem as below

Firstly, the default images **need to be saved** on cloudinary. 
eg

```
<%= cl_image_tag("non_existing_id.png", width: 100, height: 100, default_image: "avatar.png") %>
```

if you dont want to load default image from cloudinary but from our localhost, add the below  code in a partial and use this partial.

```
- if user.avatar.present?
  = cl_image_tag(user.avatar.filename, width: 46, height: 46)
- else
  = image_tag 'noPic_80.png', style: 'width:46px; height:46px;'
```